# How can I do Flutter grid menu horizantal scrollable?

Tags: flutter

How do I make a grid menu like here?

ex: http://sindevo.com/blix/preview.html

[example this menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjZoK.png)

I tried many ways. Listview builder , gridview builder ..... But I couldn't do the same this menu.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Hey this might help you:

```
 Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.35,
        child: ListView.builder(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            itemCount: 2,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.6,
            child: Container(
                child: GridView.count(
                  crossAxisCount: 2,
                  childAspectRatio: 1.0,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                  mainAxisSpacing: 4.0,
                  crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Card(
                      elevation: 4,
                      child: IconButton(
                        onPressed: (){

                        },
                        icon: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Icon(
                              Icons.shopping_cart,
                              color: Colors.blue,
                              size: 23.0,
                            ),
                            Text("Shop")
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Card(
                      elevation: 4,
                      child: IconButton(
                        onPressed: (){

                        },
                        icon: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Icon(
                              Icons.shopping_cart,
                              color: Colors.blue,
                              size: 23.0,
                            ),
                            Text("Shop")
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Card(
                      elevation: 4,
                      child: IconButton(
                        onPressed: (){

                        },
                        icon: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Icon(
                              Icons.shopping_cart,
                              color: Colors.blue,
                              size: 23.0,
                            ),
                            Text("Shop")
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Card(
                      elevation: 4,
                      child: IconButton(
                        onPressed: (){

                        },
                        icon: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Icon(
                              Icons.shopping_cart,
                              color: Colors.blue,
                              size: 23.0,
                            ),
                            Text("Shop")
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Card(
                      elevation: 4,
                      child: IconButton(
                        onPressed: (){

                        },
                        icon: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Icon(
                              Icons.shopping_cart,
                              color: Colors.blue,
                              size: 23.0,
                            ),
                            Text("Shop")
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Card(
                      elevation: 4,
                      child: IconButton(
                        onPressed: (){

                        },
                        icon: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Icon(
                              Icons.shopping_cart,
                              color: Colors.blue,
                              size: 23.0,
                            ),
                            Text("Shop")
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),

                  ],
                )
            ),
          );
        }),
      ),
```

Comment: Thank you so much, But when if count of menu greather than 6 , scrolling horizontal next menu items. But your codes is not possible. You can look example page

Comment: I have updated the answer. let me know if It works.

Comment: Its not work, if you can edit text for example : shop1 , shop2 , shop3 and then you will can missing :/

Comment: what? I don't understand.